# Setting up a local environment to test styles on ADFS login

Tags: adfs

I am wondering if anyone can point me in the right direction of how to setup a local environment to test the CSS of the A~DFS login. Everywhere sends me to the CSS but no HTML.

There is a huge security process that I have to go through to be able to upload a file to the live ADFS system so I wanted to test locally that the CSS changes I was making were correct.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You needs an instance of Windows Server and run up a VM in Azure.

You need access to a DC and you need admin rights to the server.

These [steps](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2015/08/21/openid-connect-web-sign-on-with-adfs-in-windows-server-2016-tp3/) are a good guide.